# Unsupported architecture armv7s error when using Xcode 4.5.1

Tags: xcode4.5, ios-frameworks

I updated my app to support iOS 6 in late September. I was able to archive and upload to the store without an issue. Now, I am unable to validate my archive file and instead receive an error: iPad/iPod Touch: application contains unsupported architecture(s):  armv7s (-19031). I have not changed any code and I have not changed any of the frameworks used in the project. Specifically, I am using the following frameworks:  SystemConfiguration, Foundation, UIKit, CoreGraphics and AVFoundation. The advice I have seen in other posts on StackOverflow is to remove armv7s support until all frameworks have updated to include armv7s support. However, I can't imagine these common frameworks do not support the new architecture. The two changes I have made since my last update are: 1) upgrading to OS X 10.7.5 and 2) upgrading to Xcode 4.5.1. Has anyone else seen similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is an issue with Xcode 4.5.1. After upgrading to Xcode 4.5.2, the error went away, and I was able to upload successfully.